# how to remove a directory that is a drive?

Tags: windows-10

I usually use Linux as main OS. For a customer project, I need to use Windows. I boot natively in Windows. Inside a folder on another drive, there is a folder called C: that is literally my drive C:

When I try to delete C: folder, it try to delete my C drive.

1. How can I remove this folder?
2. I suspect a Linux software result this. How can I reproduce it in windows?

I tried `rmdir path` with single quote, double quote, ending with a backslash, etc. and I got:

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Thank you!

**File explorer view**

[image]

**Command line view**

[image]

Comment: If this is *literally* your C: drive, then it is a junction point.

Comment: Unfortunately, if it is also named `C:`, then I'm not sure how you would go about removing it.

Comment: What makes you think that deleting this folder will delete your C:\ (local disk) drive?

Comment: Can you try this: Open a command prompt, navigate to the folder in your screenshot, the one that contains that `C:` entry, run `DIR`, and copy and paste the exact link that it gives you for that entry?

Comment: @Edd Because I tried it and saw it was deleting the C drive with a progress bar 1 file of 438903428 files deleting.

Comment: @SebastienDErrico can you rename the folder?

Comment: It's very odd to have 438 million files on your C: drive though, but I assume that was just a *very high number* to indicate what was happening.

Comment: @Edd renaming does not display any error message but the folder stay the same name

Comment: @Ed I tried with command line and I got: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Also try opening a command prompt in administrator mode (windows key, type in cmd, right-click the "Command Prompt" entry and select "Run as administrator) and then in the command prompt run `chkdsk X: /f` where X: is the drive letter of the drive that has that subfolder.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Here a printscreen of the command line. Checking now for the chkdsk command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably remove this folder by accessing it using the UNC notation `\\?\C:\C:`, where `\\?\C:\` would be your C: drive root.

How this can be created, I have no idea. Normally, Windows should prevent creation of directories and files containing a colon (and some other characters like backslash, question mark, asterisk and semicolon). Maybe it is not a colon but another Unicode character just looking similar to a colon?

Comment: If it is *literally* going to try to remove the contents of their C: drive then I'd say it's most likely a junction point, not just an oddly named folder.

Comment: If this is a junction point directory ​this might be able to help your remove it: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/create-delete-a-junction-link-on-windows-10